# How to pass an array into a function, and return the results with an array

Tags: php

So I'm trying to learn how to pass arrays through a function, so that I can get around PHP's inability to return multiple values. Haven't been able to get anything to work so far, but here is my best try. Can anybody point out where I'm going wrong?

```
function foo($array)
{
    $array[3]=$array[0]+$array[1]+$array[2];
    return $array;
}

$waffles[0]=1;
$waffles[1]=2;
$waffles[2]=3;
foo($waffles);

echo $waffles[3];
```

For clarification: I want to be able to pass multiple variables into a function, do something, then return multiple variables back out while keeping them seperate. This was just an example I was trying to get working as a work around for not being able to return multiple variables from an array

Comment: By the way, the reason it's spaced all funny is because this was the only way I could keep it from clumping everything on one line :-/

Comment: you can use the "code" button on the editor.

Comment: Try using the "code sample" button...it's got a bunch of 0's and 1's on it...like code ;)

Comment: thought I did. Probably my fault

Comment: For the sake of posterity, what I was trying to accomplish with this problem was to alter an array by using a function. What I was having a hard time grasping at the time wasn't passing by reference so much as what it meant for a function to `return` a value, and what happened with the value returned.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You seem to be looking for pass-by-reference, to do that make your function look this way (note the ampersand):

```
function foo(&$array)
{
    $array[3]=$array[0]+$array[1]+$array[2];
}
```

Alternately, you can assign the return value of the function to a variable:

```
function foo($array)
{
    $array[3]=$array[0]+$array[1]+$array[2];
    return $array;
}

$waffles = foo($waffles)
```

Comment: How do I use this:
function foo($minheight = 'Hello World') {
    echo "The height is : $minheight <br>";
    $minheight[3]=$minheight[0]+$minheight[1]+$minheight[2];
    return $minheight;
}

$setHeight= foo($setHeight);

Comment: To be clear, you only need to pass an array by reference (1st example) when, as in the case of the question here, the purpose of the function is to change the value outside of the function. Otherwise, as noted in SoapBox's 2nd example, you can simply pass and return an array or a single value, depending on what you are doing in the function.

Answer (score 11):

You're passing the array into the function by copy. Only objects are passed by reference in PHP, and an array is not an object. Here's what you do (note the &)

```
function foo(&$arr) { # note the &
  $arr[3] = $arr[0]+$arr[1]+$arr[2];
}
$waffles = array(1,2,3);
foo($waffles);
echo $waffles[3]; # prints 6
```

That aside, I'm not sure why you would do that particular operation like that. Why not just return the sum instead of assigning it to a new array element?

Comment: I want to be able to pass multiple variables into a function, do something, then return multiple variables back out while keeping them seperate. This was just an example I was trying to get working

Answer (score 5):

```
function foo(Array $array)
{
     return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$waffles = foo($waffles);
```

Or pass the array by reference, like suggested in the other answers.

In addition, you can add new elements to an array without writing the index, e.g.

```
$waffles = array(1,2,3); // filling on initialization
```

or

```
$waffles = array();
$waffles[] = 1;
$waffles[] = 2;
$waffles[] = 3;
```

On a sidenote, if you want to sum all values in an array, use [`array_sum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Answer (score 2):

I always return multiple values by using a combination of `list()` and `array()`s:

```
function DecideStuffToReturn() {
    $IsValid = true;
    $AnswerToLife = 42;

    // Build the return array.
    return array($IsValid, $AnswerToLife);
}

// Part out the return array in to multiple variables.
list($IsValid, $AnswerToLife) = DecideStuffToReturn();
```

You can name them whatever you like. I chose to keep the function variables and the return variables the same for consistency but you can call them whatever you like.

See [`list()`](http://php.net/list) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

i know a Class is a bit the overkill

```
class Foo
{

 private $sum = NULL;

 public function __construct($array)
 {
   $this->sum[] = $array;
   return $this;
 }

 public function getSum()
 {
   $sum = $this->sum;
   for($i=0;$i<count($sum);$i++)
   {
      // get the last array index
      $res[$i] = $sum[$i] + $sum[count($sum)-$i];
   }
   return $res;
 }


}


$fo = new Foo($myarray)->getSum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to return 'multiple values' in PHP. You can return a single value, which might be an array.

```
function foo($test1, $test2, $test3)
{
    return array($test1, $test2, $test3);
}
$test1 = "1";
$test2 = "2";
$test3 = "3";

$arr = foo($test1, $test2, $test3);

$test1 = $arr[0];
$test2 = $arr[1];
$test3 = $arr[2];
```

Comment: why is `foo()` called `giveme()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it. This way I can actually get a function to simulate returning multiple values;

```
function foo($array) 
{ 
    foreach($array as $_key => $_value) 
    {
       $str .= "{$_key}=".$_value.'&';
    }
    return $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
} 

/* Set the variables to pass to function, in an Array */

    $waffles['variable1'] = "value1"; 
    $waffles['variable2'] = "value2"; 
    $waffles['variable3'] = "value3"; 

/* Call Function */

    parse_str( foo( $waffles ));

/* Function returns multiple variable/value pairs */

    echo $variable1 ."<br>";
    echo $variable2 ."<br>";
    echo $variable3 ."<br>";
```

*Especially usefull if you want, for example **all fields in a database** 
to be returned as variables, named the same as the database table *fields*.
See '**db_fields( )**' function below*.

**For example, if you have a query**

```
select login, password, email from members_table where id = $id
```

**Function returns multiple variables:**

```
$login, $password and $email
```

***Here is the function:***

```
function db_fields($field, $filter, $filter_by,  $table = 'members_table') {

 /*
    This function will return as variable names, all fields that you request, 
    and the field values assigned to the variables as variable values.  

    $filter_by = TABLE FIELD TO FILTER RESULTS BY
    $filter =  VALUE TO FILTER BY
    $table = TABLE TO RUN QUERY AGAINST

    Returns single string value or ARRAY, based on whether user requests single
    field or multiple fields.

    We return all fields as variable names. If multiple rows
    are returned, check is_array($return_field); If > 0, it contains multiple rows.
    In that case, simply run parse_str($return_value) for each Array Item. 
*/
    $field = ($field == "*") ? "*,*" : $field;
    $fields = explode(",",$field);

    $assoc_array = ( count($fields) > 0 ) ? 1 : 0;

    if (!$assoc_array) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select $field from $table where $filter_by = '$filter'"));
        return ${$field} = $result[$field];
    }
    else
    {
        $query = mysql_query("select $field from $table where $filter_by = '$filter'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            foreach($row as $_key => $_value) {
                $str .= "{$_key}=".$_value.'&';
            }
            return $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a sample call to function. So, If we need to get User Data for say $user_id = 12345, from the members table with fields ID, LOGIN, PASSWORD, EMAIL:

```
$filter = $user_id;
$filter_by = "ID";
$table_name = "members_table"

parse_str(db_fields('LOGIN, PASSWORD, EMAIL', $filter, $filter_by, $table_name));

/* This will return the following variables: */

echo $LOGIN ."<br>";
echo $PASSWORD ."<br>";
echo $EMAIL ."<br>";
```

We could also call like this:

```
parse_str(db_fields('*', $filter, $filter_by, $table_name));
```

The above call would return all fields as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
$NAME = "John";
$EMAIL = "John@gmail.com";
$USERNAME = "John123";
$PASSWORD = "1234";
$array = Array ("$NAME","$EMAIL","$USERNAME","$PASSWORD");
function getAndReturn (Array $array){
    return $array;
}
print_r(getAndReturn($array));
```