# Passing an array over to new function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm building an insert page using checkboxes where members of staff can assign qualifications (read: specified marksheets) to the classes within a specified subject area, and in order to do so it checks first whether the user (read: school) has subscribed to the correct qualifications before they can be subscribed.

The checkbox page is completely built up from a WHILE loop where it prints all the classes within a subject area and the amount of checkboxes corresponding to the amount of qualifications available for that subject.

```
while ($row = $classlistresult->fetch ())
                {
                    printf ("<form method=\"post\" 
                    action=\"%s?action=4&class=%d\">\n",
                    script_name (),
                    ASSIGN_QUALIFICATIONS,
                    $row['idClass'] );

                    print ("<tr>\n");
                    $url = sprintf ("%s?action=%d&idClass=%d", 
                    script_name (), 
                    CLASS_LIST, 
                    $row["idClass"]);

                    display_cell ("td" , "<a href=\"$url\">" . $row["Class"] . "    </a>", FALSE);
                    display_cell ("td", $row["Staff"]);

                    $idClass = $row["idClass"];
                    $idstaff = $row["idStaff"];
                    $_SESSION['Class'] = $idClass;

                    $qualname = "
                    SELECT `mldb`.`qualification`.`idQualification`, `mldb`.`qualification`.`Code`
                    FROM    `mldb`.`qualification` ";
                    $qualresult = mysqli_query ($dbc, $qualname) ;
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qualresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                        {
                            $idqual = $row['idQualification'] ;
                            print ("<td><p><input type = 'checkbox'
                            name = 'addqual[]'
                            value = '$idqual'\n" ."</a>") ;
                        }
```

Now, that all works fine - and when I do an echo test wto see hether the correct class and qualifications-information is being parsed, it shows the correct array of class and qualification ID's.

Below is a fraction of the class ID's returned by this echo test:

```
58339160 58339321 58339523 5833958 58339162 58339518 58339873 58339398 58339595 58339732 58339500 58339735 58339828 58339492 58339128 58339139 58339740 583395 58339719 58339493 5833918 58339695 5833932 58339879 58339839 58339788
```

However, when I start up a new function that will update the database with the information from the checkbox page, I find myself stuck with a fixed variable for both the class ID and the qualification ID, thus generating duplication ERRORS when I try to insert data into the database:

```
class ID: 58339160
qualification ID: 3 (The very first entries of both Class and Qualification)
```

My question is: How can I pass an array over to a new function whilst still maintaining it as an array?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an array is very simple.

```
function foo($array)
{
    $array[3]=$array[0]+$array[1]+$array[2];
    return $array;
}
```

accessing array in loop

```
 function fooLoop($array)
{   $sum = 0;
    for($i= 0; $i<count($array); $i++){
         $sum = $sum + $array[$i];
         echo   $array[$i];
       }
    return $sum;
}


$waffles[0]=1;
$waffles[1]=2;
$waffles[2]=3;
foo($waffles);
```

Docs Link: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

[How to pass an array into a function, and return the results with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158848/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-function-and-return-the-results-with-an-array)

Comment: But does that mean that I have to individually call up the amount of elements in that array? Because even though there's three at the moment, this could easily end up to be 10 or 11... or is there a dynamic way of getting around that?

Comment: @Sean Limpens you can access array elements dynamically using loop and count function. I have  updated the answer. You can perform any action on elements in loop.